# magic jquery image uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, upload, import

I'm trying to make someone else's code work for iPad (and other mobile devices). One of the things that works on desktop but that fails on iPad is clicking the 'import image' button. On the desktop, it opens the dialogue box you'd expect and allows you to select an image, but on iPad clicking 'import image' does nothing.

The only code I can find that is called in response to clicking this button is as follows:

```
var clickImport = function() {
  //breakpoint here hits when I write something like "var test=9;" and 'import image' is clicked
};
```

Nothing even happens in the function.
When I step past the end of this function it goes straight into jquery.js, which appears to open the dialogue box.

All the image handling with the file reader happens AFTER you click 'ok' in the dialogue box. The problem is that I can't even get the dialogue box to open at all on the iPad. There's no "`<input type='file'>`" sort of thing in the HTML either.

Does anyone know how this could be working?? Or how I could get it to function on mobile devices? Thanks!

Comment: what does the original clickImport function do?

Comment: can you add snippet? or working jsfiddle?

Comment: @Pete: That is the original clickImport function. It doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: @JohnnyJS: Sorry, that's really the only relevant snippet I can find, and the code is absolutely huge so I can't provide a JSFiddle.